# Remove charset utf-8 from Postman Content-Type header

Tags: networking, postman

So I have a pretty basic setup, one collection with request and an example with JSON body and

```
Content-Type: application/json.
```

I also have a mock server with this collection.
I didn't change anything else except that I listed, but the server return

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Is it possible to remove it?
I also tried to disable "Encode URL automatically" and it didn't help